# How can I tell if I have already upgraded my BfA legendary cloak via completing a Horrific Vision this week?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In World of Warcraft: Battle For Azeroth you get a legendary cloak called Ashjra'kamas .  As of 2020-May it is possible to upgrade the cloak's corruption resistance each week by completing a Horrific Vision, or killing N'zoth (the final boss of the raid).  If your cloak is behind the corruption cap you can get both upgrades.

I am absent-minded, so I can't remember if I completed my Horrific Vision this week.  Is there a script or addon I can use that will tell me if I have upgraded my cloak via a Horrific Vision already this week?